# Jasmin unit test return Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $sanitizeProvider <- $sanitize

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

Below is a part of my controller

```
'use strict';
angular.module('ps.users.adminUsers').controller('AdminUsersController',
  ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$sanitize','$state', '$modal', '$log', '$timeout', 'usersApi','UserServices', 'Users', 'COMMON', 'workspacesApi', 'msg', '$filter', 'EMAIL_REGEX',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $sanitize, $state, $modal, $log, $timeout, usersApi, UserServices, Users, COMMON, workspacesApi, msg, $filter, EMAIL_REGEX) {
      var self = this,
          columnDefs, dataSource,
          limit = 10000,
          filterString;
........................
```

Here is UserServices

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ps.users.services').config(['$provide', function($provide) {

  $provide.factory('UserServices', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$sanitize','$filter', '$log', '$timeout', '$state', '$modal', 'Users', 'usersApi', 'msg',
    function($rootScope, $q, $sanitize, $filter, $log, $timeout, $state, $modal, Users, usersApi, msg) {
   .........
```

and still see this error message:
hrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) Test for AdminUsersController / Test Search For function /  Should add Admin user FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DSProvider <- DS <- Users <- UserServices
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.18/$injector/unpr?p0=DSProvider%20%3C-%20DS%20%3C-%20Users%20%3C-%20UserServices

Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 192 of 192 (1 FAILED) (0.566 secs / 0.542 secs)

Any suggestion on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have declared `ngSanitize` as a dependency while defining your App.

Once that is done, you'll have to make the following changes to your tests:

```
describe('Test for AdminUsersController /', function(){

    // load adminUsers module
    beforeEach(module('ps.users.adminUsers'));

    describe('Test Search For function / ',function() {
        /*You don't need $injector to get $controller, you'll simply get it by injecting it as a dependency as done below. 
        You'll also get the $sanitize service. Also instead of having $scope as an empty object, you should use $rootScope service's  $new method as done below.
        Lastly, you will have to add all the required dependency while mocking your controller as well. */

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $sanitize) {
            $sanitize = $sanitize;
            $rootScope = $rootScope;

            //Creating a new scope
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            //Mocking the controller
            AdminUsersController = $controller('AdminUsersController', {
                $rootScope: $rootScope,
                $scope: $scope,
                $sanitize: $sanitize
            });
        }));

        it('Should add Admin user', function ()  {
            expect(AdminUsersController).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

**Update** - 
You'll keep on getting these error messages until you provide all the required dependencies **to mock the controller**.

Here's a small working example from the code that you provided:

First of all, you're not using $log and $rootScope in your controller. So remove these unnecessary dependencies from it.

And I didn't know what some of the depencencies are, so I just created some mocks for them.

```js
var usersModule = angular.module('ps.users', []);
//Wasn't sure what these other dependencies were. So mocked them like these
usersModule.service('UserServices', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

usersModule.service('Users', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

usersModule.service('usersApi', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

usersModule.service('COMMON', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

usersModule.service('workspacesApi', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

usersModule.service('msg', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

usersModule.service('EMAIL_REGEX', [
  function() {
    return {}
  }
]);

angular.module('ps.users.adminUsers', ['ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ps.users']).controller('AdminUsersController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$sanitize', '$state', '$modal', '$log', '$timeout', 'usersApi', 'UserServices', 'Users', 'COMMON', 'workspacesApi', 'msg', '$filter', 'EMAIL_REGEX',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $sanitize, $state, $modal, $log, $timeout, usersApi, UserServices, Users, COMMON, workspacesApi, msg, $filter, EMAIL_REGEX) {
    //Your code here
  }
]);


// TEST CASE
describe('Test for AdminUsersController /', function() {
  beforeEach(module('ps.users.adminUsers'));
  describe('Test Search For function / ', function() {
    /*You don't need $injector to get $controller, you'll simply get it by injecting it as a dependency as done below. 
    You'll also get the $sanitize service. Also instead of having $scope as an empty object, you should use $rootScope service's  $new method as done below.
    Lastly, you will have to add all the required dependency while mocking your controller as well. */

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $sanitize, $state, $modal, $log, $timeout, usersApi, UserServices, Users, COMMON, workspacesApi, msg, $filter, EMAIL_REGEX) {
      $sanitize = $sanitize;
      $rootScope = $rootScope;
      $state = $state;
      $modal = $modal;
      $log = $log;
      $timeout = $timeout;
      usersApi = usersApi;
      UserServices = UserServices;
      Users = Users;
      COMMON = COMMON;
      workspacesApi = workspacesApi;
      msg = msg;
      $filter = $filter;
      EMAIL_REGEX = EMAIL_REGEX;

      //Creating a new scope
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      //Mocking the controller
      AdminUsersController = $controller('AdminUsersController', {
        $rootScope: $rootScope,
        $scope: $scope,
        $sanitize: $sanitize,
        $state: $state,
        $modal: $modal,
        $log: $log,
        $timeout: $timeout,
        usersApi: usersApi,
        UserServices: UserServices,
        Users: Users,
        COMMON: COMMON,
        workspacesApi: workspacesApi,
        msg: msg,
        $filter: $filter,
        EMAIL_REGEX: EMAIL_REGEX
      });
    }));

    it('Should add Admin user', function() {
      expect(AdminUsersController).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still got the error message after adding all required dependency. I updated my post with new error message

Comment: Hi Ajemra, Thanks for the help. Still had an issue with testing controller. I have updated my post with controller, test and error. Can you please take a quick look to see What I have missed?

Comment: Hi Ajemra, Still have the error message about Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: DSProvider <- DS <- Users <- UserServices . I just posted my UserServices too. Your help is greatly appreciated. Would you please take a quick look

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but sorry, I can't further spoon feed you.